# Passing global variables through the window object - is it a good idea?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

Is it a good idea to pass global variables through the `window` object in a Node - React - Redux app? Other parts of the app (JSP) besides my code may use global variables stored in `window` - it's hard to tell.

I've noticed it in a project where I'm collaborating with others, and wanted to check with the S.O. community first before talking about it with them.

My personal preference would be to avoid using global variables as much as possible, and to pass information through `state` instead, or if need be, set environment variables with Node's `process.env['FOO'] = 'bar'`.

Thoughts?

Comment: It's not a good idea to use global variables at all.  State should be stored in objects that are created as needed and then shared with others who need access to that state who can keep a reference to that object.

Comment: It's not a good idea to try using `window` in node.

Comment: Is there any reason for this - specifically regarding not using `window` in connection to Node? I've done some Googling but can't find any concrete reasoning. Regarding not using globals, there's lots, but specifically regarding `windows` and Node, there isn't. Again, my personal preference is to use state instead. Even just a link to an article would be appreciated.